# Why datatable do not append one zero in left of the day in date whhen fetched from the database(sql)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datetime, datatable

I have date saved in sql DB and it is in the format `01-12-2016` (I mean it appends zero when single digit of day and month) but the same date when i fetch from database and store it in data table I get this 
format

```
1/12/2016
```

**How to append zero to it ?** And why it eliminates zero at start ?

Comment: How are you binding it to the datatable? Please show us some code.

Comment: Could you please include the code that you are using for populating the dataTable

Comment: show the code so that we can figure it out.

Comment: Character column data type? Which dbms? (Most of them aren't ANSI SQL when it comes to date/time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fetching date as a **string**, then do the following

```
_date = DateTime.Parse("1/12/2016"); // Convert to DateTime
string reqDate = _date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // Get in the required format
```

However, if it is already a **DateTime**

```
string reqDate = dateFromDb.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```